# Java Password Pattern identify

Tags: java, regex, passwords

Can you tell what this pattern does in java??

```
private static final String PASSWORD_PATTERN = "^.[\\S]{5,}$";
```

If you can tell me what does it do symbol by symbol. Thanx.

Comment: Look at documentation http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/

Comment: "Any character followed by five or more non-whitespace characters."

Comment: visit the site http://www.vogella.com/articles/JavaRegularExpressions/article.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The string should start (`^`) with any character (`.`) followed by at least 5 (`{5,}`) non witespace characters (`[\\S]`) then it should end (`$`)

Answer (score 0):

^. - starts with any character (except line break) 
[\S]{5,} - followed by 5 or more non-white spaces 
$ - followed by end of line